# Simple Jquery Menu button repeats animation, how can I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have simple animation on website. When user have mouse over button there is animation (background from button appears). It works fine, but when user start fast moves between button animation just go crazy and repeat animation on all buttons.

Buttons:

```
       <div id="menu_lewe">
          <ul>
            //BUTTON NR. 1
            <li class="menu">
                <ul>
                <li class="button"></li>
                <a href="#manifest"><li class="menu_glowne">MANIFEST</li></a>
                </ul>
            </li>

            //BUTTON NR.2
            <li class="menu">
                <ul>
                <li class="button"></li>
                <a href="#marki"><li class="menu_glowne">NASZE MARKI</li></a>
                </ul>
            </li>


          </ul>
       </div>
```

Code for animation:

```
$('.button').css({'opacity':0});

$('.menu').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find("li").animate({'opacity':1},200);
});


$('.menu').mouseout(function(){
    $('.button').animate({'opacity':0},200);
});
```

What i should change to make this buttons animation more natural?

Comment: you could try adding `.stop()` before `.animate()` to prevent animations stacking up. e.g. `...stop().animate({'opacity'...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.menu', function() {

  $(this).find("li").stop().animate({'opacity':1},200);

}).on('mouseout', '.menu', function() {

  $('.button').stop().animate({'opacity':0},200);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery queues up animations. So if you are quickly hovering in and out over an element that has animations for these interactions, it will keep on animating until all those animation are executed.

```
===========================================
| HoverIn   | starting hoverIn animation  |
| HoverOut  | ...                         |
| HoverIn   | ending   hoverIn animation  |
| HoverOut  | starting hoverOut animation |
|           | ...                         |
|           | ending   hoverOutanimation  |
|           | starting hoverIn animation  |
| ...         ...                         |
===========================================
```

If you want to clear all animations that are queued, you can use `.stop()`:

```
$('.menu').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find("li").stop(true).animate({'opacity':1},200);
});


$('.menu').mouseout(function(){
    $('.button').stop(true).animate({'opacity':0},200);
});
```

The parameter `true` is passed in to clear all animations that are still queued on the current element.

[jQuery docs on *.stop()*](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

```
 $(this).find("li").stop().animate({'opacity':1},200);
 $('.button').stop().animate({'opacity':0},200);
```

It will stop the current queue on the element and start the new animation.